# Pulling Image directly from URL directory and stored it in sql server db

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, url, remote-access

Hi I have a Table Called Temp
with two columns Name (varchar) and Image (VarBinary(max)) datatype respectively

```
Insert into Temp
  (
  Name,
  Image     
  )
Select
  'Bob',
  (
select BulkColumn from openrowset (Bulk 'http://pngimg.com/upload/apple_PNG2579.png',Single_Blob) as Apple
  )
```

This query errors out saying 'Cannot bulk load because the file "http://pngimg.com/upload/apple_PNG2579.png" could not be opened. Operating system error code 123(error not found). However when i click on the url it is perfectly valid.

Anyone up for suggestions?

Please note there is a way to store the image on the local server and then access it. However i am trying to find a way to directly do it within sql
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't do this directly from SQL Server (and for good reason!).  As you say it is trivial when you have already downloaded the image and stored it locally.  Another alternative is to use SSIS as it has a mechanism for pulling data from the web (although I think this is to handle XML so it might not work with images).

Comment: yes Richard SSIS could be the alternative. but i am totally new to it.  So i guess the easiest way would be to use a local file that is downloaded on a local server. Thank you for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pngimg.com/upload/apple_PNG2579.png seems like an URL to me. 
BULK INSERT is expecting a file name like c:\image\image.jpg

Using URL as the source is not supported with BULK INSERT.
Try to download the files locally first, then insert into the table. 
SSIS, for example, has the functionality to download HTTP content.

Comment: Thank you hexyKing. I'll mark your answer as the chosen for now. as all the suggestion points me either to downloading the file locally and using ir or to use SSIS package.